# Is it possible to store the date DD/MM/YYYYY in SQL

Tags: sql, date, format

I have to store a date value which has YYYYY i.e. 28/03/10248 into my database.
Is it possible to store this value of year using DATE datatype ?
Could someone help me on this

Comment: Dates are stored in an internal format in all databases.  You can fetch them and format the result as a string as well.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. What is the scenario where that does not represent a data input error?

Comment: I have to enter the date 28/03/10248 into my database and the column datatype i used is DATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is limit for year value

For example;

in [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)'s limits is January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999

in [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html)' limits is 4713 BC to 294276 AD

Comment: My vote put your reputation over 100.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: Oh.. then this scenario is not possible then in my case.
Thank you so much for your help :)